# How to limit the time input to only be accpetable within a timeperiod in Python

Tags: python, datetime, input, time, range

I have succesfully made a function that asks the user for a valid time by importing the module Datetime. If the user doesn't enter a valid time the question will be asked until he/she does.
But the problem is that im currently running a zoo, who has open between 08:00 - 22:00. How do I extend my code so the user only can enter a valid time between that timeperiod? Help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
def input_time():

    while True:
        try:
            time = input("What time do you plan to be here? (HH:MM): ")
            pattern_time = ('%H:%M')
            time = datetime.strptime(time, pattern_time)
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a valid time,try again")
            continue
        else:
            break
    return time

time = input_time()
```

Comment: This is Python, I presume?

Comment: Yes, I have no clarified that it is Python

Answer (score 0):

Sorry no one has answered this. The time_struct provides member fields that you can test:

```
while True:
  try:
    t = input("What time do you plan to be here? (HH:MM): ")
    pattern_time = ('%H:%M')
    t = time.strptime(t, pattern_time)
    if not (8 <= t.tm_hour <= 22):
      print("The zoo is only open from 8:00 to 22:00")
      continue
  except ValueError:
    print("Not a valid time, try again")
    continue
  else:
    break
return t
```

Also, be careful with variable names.